# Definig element.sortable()-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui

My html table supports changing the row-order using mouse drag and drop. The used jquery-ui version is v1.12.1. It works for old tables (i.e. those whose row count is known since load of the page), but it doesn't work for rows added after the page has been loaded. I think the reason is that the below sortable()-function is inside document.ready()-function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#luok_table tbody').sortable({
          stop: function( event, ui ){
              $(this).find('tr').each(function(i){
                  $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, i) );                
                  $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
                      $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, i) );
                      $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, i) );
                  }); 
              });
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

If that's the reason, where should I define the sortable()-function ?
The table rows are added by jquery-formset-js-script:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts)
    {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formset.defaults, opts),
            flatExtraClasses = options.extraClasses.join(' '),
            
            $$ = $(this),
            

            applyExtraClasses = function(row, ndx) {
                if (options.extraClasses) {
                    row.removeClass(flatExtraClasses);
                    row.addClass(options.extraClasses[ndx % options.extraClasses.length]);
                }
            },

            updateElementIndex = function(elem, prefix, ndx) {
                var idRegex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+-)|(^)'),
                    replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
                if (elem.attr("for")) elem.attr("for", elem.attr("for").replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('id')) elem.attr('id', elem.attr('id').replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('name')) elem.attr('name', elem.attr('name').replace(idRegex, replacement));
            },

            hasChildElements = function(row) {
                return row.find('input,select,textarea,label').length > 0;
            },

            insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
                if (row.is('TR')) {
                    // If the forms are laid out in table rows, insert
                    // the remove button into the last table cell:
                    row.children(':last').append('<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass +'" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText + '</a>');
                } else if (row.is('UL') || row.is('OL')) {
                    // If they're laid out as an ordered/unordered list,
                    // insert an <li> after the last list item:
                    row.append('<li><a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a></li>');
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, just insert the remove button as the
                    // last child element of the form's container:
                    row.append('<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>');
                }
                row.find('a.' + options.deleteCssClass).click(function() {
                    var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
                        del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]');
                    if (del.length) {
                        // We're dealing with an inline formset; rather than remove
                        // this form from the DOM, we'll mark it as deleted and hide
                        // it, then let Django handle the deleting:
                        del.val('on');
                        row.hide();
                    } else {
                        row.remove();
                        // Update the TOTAL_FORMS form count.
                        // Also update names and IDs for all remaining form controls so they remain in sequence:
                        var forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
                        $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
                        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                            applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
                            forms.eq(i).find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                                updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    // If a post-delete callback was provided, call it with the deleted form:
                    if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
                    
                    return false;
                });
            };

        $$.each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this),
                del = row.find('input:checkbox[id $= "-DELETE"]');
            if (del.length) {
                // If you specify "can_delete = True" when creating an inline formset,
                // Django adds a checkbox to each form in the formset.
                // Replace the default checkbox with a hidden field:
                del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" />');
                del.remove();
            }
            if (hasChildElements(row)) {
                insertDeleteLink(row);
                row.addClass(options.formCssClass);
                applyExtraClasses(row, i);
            }
        });
        
        if ($$.length) {
            var addButton, template;
            if (options.formTemplate) {
                // If a form template was specified, we'll clone it to generate new form instances:
                template = (options.formTemplate instanceof $) ? options.formTemplate : $(options.formTemplate);
                template.removeAttr('id').addClass(options.formCssClass).addClass('formset-custom-template');
                template.find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, 2012);
                });
                insertDeleteLink(template);
            } else {
                // Otherwise, use the last form in the formset; this works much better if you've got
                // extra (>= 1) forms (thnaks to justhamade for pointing this out):
                template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
                template.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]').remove();
                template.find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    // If this is a checkbox or radiobutton, uncheck it.
                    // This fixes Issue 1, reported by Wilson.Andrew.J:
                    if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                        elem.attr('checked', false);
                    } else {
                        elem.val('');
                    }
                });
            }
            // FIXME: Perhaps using $.data would be a better idea?
            options.formTemplate = template;

            if ($$.attr('tagName') == 'TR') {
                // If forms are laid out as table rows, insert the
                // "add" button in a new table row:
                var numCols = $$.eq(0).children().length;
                $$.parent().append('<tr><td colspan="' + numCols + '"><a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a></tr>');
                addButton = $$.parent().find('tr:last a');
                addButton.parents('tr').addClass(options.formCssClass + '-add');
            } else {
                // Otherwise, insert it immediately after the last form:
                $$.filter(':last').after('<a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a>');
                addButton = $$.filter(':last').next();
            }
            addButton.click(function() {
                var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val()),
                    row = options.formTemplate.clone(true).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
                    buttonRow = $(this).parents('tr.' + options.formCssClass + '-add').get(0) || this;
                applyExtraClasses(row, formCount);
                row.insertBefore($(buttonRow)).show();
                row.find('input,select,textarea,label').each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, formCount);
                });
                
                $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount + 1);
                // If a post-add callback was supplied, call it with the added form:
                if (options.added) options.added(row);
                return false;
                
            });
        }
        return $$;
    }

    /* Setup plugin defaults */
    $.fn.formset.defaults = {
        prefix: 'form',                  // The form prefix for your django formset
        formTemplate: null,              // The jQuery selection cloned to generate new form instances
        addText: 'add another',          // Text for the add link
        deleteText: 'remove',            // Text for the delete link
        addCssClass: 'add-row',          // CSS class applied to the add link
        deleteCssClass: 'delete-row',    // CSS class applied to the delete link
        formCssClass: 'dynamic-form',    // CSS class applied to each form in a formset
        extraClasses: [],                // Additional CSS classes, which will be applied to each form in turn
        added: null,                     // Function called each time a new form is added
        removed: null                    // Function called each time a form is deleted
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: You must `refresh` after you add a row.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot @Twisty. I don't properly undestand how this jquery-formset-js-script works, could you still suggest the best way to add that referesh?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty well, pls see https://github.com/miettinj/jquery-question for a reproducible example. I just figured out the reason for the problem: It is that added table rows have incorrect ids. The correct id is id_fs_luok_<row-number-1>-techical_name, but ids for the added rows are fs_luok-<row-number-1>-id_fs_luok-<row-count-at-page-load>-techical_name.

Comment: My idea was to fix the ids in added fuction, but when trying it I noticed that it doesn't even detect the added row in the table - it just detects the rows that were created before the latest add. So I don't know how to fix ! (Of course it is a very ugly solution to 1st create incorrect ids and then fix them, but I don't know how to get correct ones)

Comment: Perhaps I found something intresting. The problem naming problem does not repeat with <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery.formset.js"></script>, but it repeats with a modified formset.js, which is used in my example.

Comment: Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh